# How to create SAS token for azure blob storage container with f permissions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azure-sas, shared-access-signatures

[These docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags-container) refer to needing `f` SAS permissions to do filter operations. How can I generate a SAS token with these permissions? I can't do it from the web interface and the `az` tool doesn't consider `f` a valid `--permissions` flag.

In the end I want to be able to use the rest API using curl to fiddle with the find by tags feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Az CLI [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-generate-sas-optional-parameters), `f` is a valid permission:

> **--permissions**: The permissions the SAS grants. Allowed values: (a)dd (c)reate (d)elete (e)xecute (f)ilter_by_tags (i)set_immutability_policy (l)ist (m)ove (r)ead (t)ag (w)rite (x)delete_previous_version (y)permanent_delete. Do not use if a stored access policy is referenced with --id that specifies this value. Can be combined.

You should probably upgrade your CLI version (I'm using v2.38.0):

```powershell
az upgrade
```

I was able to generate a SAS using this command:

```powershell
az storage container generate-sas `
  --name "<container-name>" `
  --account-name <account-name> `
  --auth-mode login --as-user `
  --permissions f --expiry 2022-08-01
```